# AngularJS Calling a Function from a Directive on a Controller set by the $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have setup a stateProvider, which sets a different controller for each Tab:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url : "/home",
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).state('top', {
        url : "/top",
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : 'TopCtrl'
    }).state('trending', {
        url : "/trending",
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : 'TrendingCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

The main controller is applied like so:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $location, $log) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old) {
        switch (current) {
        case 0:
            $location.url("/home");
            break;
        case 1:
            $location.url("/top");
            break;
        case 2:
            $location.url("/trending");
            break;
        }
    });
});
...
<body ng-app="storeApp" layout="row" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-cloak>
```

I also created a directive which is applied to the tab container:

```
app.directive("autoLoad", function ($window) {
    return {
        scope: {
            load: '&load'
        },
        controller : function($scope, $element) {
            var scroller = $element;
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 100)) {
                    console.log("LOG 1");
                    $scope.load(); // LOAD POSTS
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The Tab Container:

```
<div flex layout="column" tabIndex="-1" role="main"
    class="md-whiteframe-z2" auto-load load="loadMorePosts()">
    <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="center center">
```

Each of the Controllers listed above: HomeCtrl, TopCtrl and TrendingCtrl look like this:

```
app.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, controllerManager) {
    // LOAD MORE POSTS:
    $scope.loadMorePosts = function() {
        console.log("LOG 2");
    };
});
```

Each controller has its own loadMorePosts function. For some context, I am creating an infinite scroll system, so when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the loadMorePosts function is called. In this case however, the function never gets called and "LOG 2" is never logged. "LOG 1" Gets called however, so the scrolling logic works.

I figured the issue might be that the scope that is used inside of the directive refers to the scope of the MainCtrl controller and not the respective controllers set by the stateProvier. I have attempted to apply a ng-controller dynamically to the tab container, but that results in a "Multiple Directive Error".

Again, I am just making an assumption that that is causing the issue, I may be wrong.

EDIT: The issue appears to be that the scope refers to the mainCtrl controller.
If I put the loadMorePosts method inside of that controller, the function is called. So how do I make sure that the scope is referencing the controller of the current tab instead of the mainCtrl.

EDIT: The html for the tab container:

```
<body ng-app="storeApp" layout="row" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-cloak>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/html/main.html"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/html/login.html"></script>
<div flex layout="column" tabIndex="-1" role="main"
    class="md-whiteframe-z2" auto-load load="loadMorePosts">
    <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <h1>
        <img id="mainLogo" src="../images/logo.png" height="5%">
    </h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-center-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
        <md-tab>
            <md-tab-label>
                <md-icon class="in-line" md-font-library="material-icons">home</md-icon>
                <div class="in-line">New</div>
            </md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <div ui-view flex></div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab>
            <md-tab-label>
                <md-icon class="in-line" md-font-library="material-icons">star</md-icon>
                <div class="in-line">Top</div>
            </md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <div ui-view flex></div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
       <md-tab>
            <md-tab-label>
                <md-icon class="in-line" md-font-library="material-icons">whatshot</md-icon>
                <div class="in-line">Hot</div>
            </md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <div ui-view flex></div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs> 
</div>

...
```

Comment: Just tried that. Its still not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
app.directive("autoLoad", function ($window) {
    return {
        scope: {
            load: '=' // here you specify that the name load is same as in the attribute
        },
        controller : function($scope, $element) {
            var scroller = $element;
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 100)) {
                    console.log("LOG 1");
                    $scope.load(); // LOAD POSTS
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Update**

change html like this,

```
<div flex layout="column" tabIndex="-1" role="main"
    class="md-whiteframe-z2" auto-load load="loadMorePosts">
```

**Update 2**

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $location, $log) {
    $scope.loadMorePosts = function() {
      console.log("main controller");
    };
});

app.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, controllerManager) {
    // LOAD MORE POSTS:
    $scope.$parent.loadMorePosts = function() {
        console.log("Home controller");
    };
});
```

Comment: Setting the load to "=" causes: Uncaught TypeError: $scope.load is not a function

Comment: @user3024235, change the html also. (see the updated answer)

Comment: The issue is that the scope is referencing the mainCtrl controller and not the other controllers that hold the function.

Comment: @user3024235, can you please give us the full html in the question. So that we can see how you used all controllers.

Comment: Updated the Question.

Comment: You are a god among men!

Comment: @user3024235, thanks for your compliment :) If you are interested to see my blog please follow this, https://abhilashpullelil.wordpress.com/